# Filter by rating drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope I can explain this right. I am building a bookmark app, where the user can store links to their favorite sites, and give them a 1-5 star rating. There is a drop-down menu where the user can choose to only show bookmarks that have a 4-star rating and above, a 3-star rating and above, etc... 
I know I have to do some kind of conditional or inequality statement, but I can't figure out how to say "when I click on that particular option, I want to filter my bookmark array and display the filtered items on my page." My issue is not the filtering part, but how to actually target the option in the drop-down menu. 
I'm trying to get this done using jQuery

HTML for drop-down menu:

```
<div class="filter-menu">
        <select id="dropdown" name="rating">
            <option disabled value></option>Filter by rating:</option>
            <option value=5>5 stars</option>
            <option value=4>4 stars & above</option>
            <option value=3>3 stars & above</option>
            <option value=2>2 stars & above</option>
            <option value=1>1 star & above</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function handleRatingFilter(value){
    $('.filter-menu').on('click', '#dropdown', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('dropdown menu option clicked!');

      if (value === 1){
        const bookmarks = STORE.list.filter(bookmark => bookmark.rating >= 1);
        return bookmarks;
      }
      renderStore();
    });
  }
```

Obviously my function doesn't work and I might be completely off, but that's my starting point and my logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.filter-menu').on('click', '#dropdown', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('dropdown menu option clicked!');

    var value = $(this).val(); // Here to get value
    if (value === 1){
      const bookmarks = STORE.list.filter(bookmark => bookmark.rating >= 1);
      return bookmarks;
    }
    renderStore();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function handleRatingFilter(){
        $('.filter-menu').on('change', '#dropdown', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('dropdown menu option clicked!');
            const value = event.currentTarget.value;
            if (value === 1){
                const bookmarks = STORE.list.filter(bookmark => bookmark.rating >= 1);
                return bookmarks;
            }
            renderStore();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment or explanation regarding on the block of code that you posted as answer.